# Bash scripting. Hiding output of one particular command in a script thats output to a file

Tags: bash, grep, nested, pipe

This script of mine is slowly getting larger. It has its output piped to a file on invocation (which is later used to build an email body), however, I have one particular command that's invoked in that script whose output I want to trim down.

I was trying to do

```
./somecommand | egrep "pattern1|pattern2"
```

Which works fine in a regular console window, however when snuck into my larger script, the pipe to egrep gets ignored and the whole output of the "./somecommand" lands in the output of the parent script.

How can fix?

I'm keeping this question vague to avoid copy pasting the whole damn thing. More info can be provided on request. And yes, scripts within scripts within scripts, we need to go deeper, etc. I'm up to five scripts so-far handling different tasks as part of a larger multi-server backup operation. The main operating script is output to a text file which an email body is built around, this serves as the logging that the end user sees. One particular script I'm calling from within the main script is quite 'noisy', hence the egrep to grab just the output relevant to the users.

Thanks folks!

Comment: you could turn on shell debugging with `set -vx`, and edit your question to show just the place where this code is executed, with a little bit of the output. Are there any '*' chars in your egrep patterns? Do any of your scripts use the `exec ...2>&1` capture/redirection internally? Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible ./somecommand is sending its output to stderr instead of stdout?  You could try:

```
./somecommand 2>&1 | egrep "pattern1|pattern2"
```

Comment: Another thought... if ssh is involved in your daisy-chain of processes, could ./somecommand be running locally at the command line, but remotely in your script?

Comment: Nope, shouldn't be going to stderr but I'll try that when I get back to work on it tomorrow. All commands run locally, no SSH involved. Thanks

Comment: Is anything affecting the inputs of ./somecommand, whether piped, on params, or in ENV variables, that would make it produce different output in context than it would isolating it at the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try grep -v option? Do you get single line output for all the scripts that you have inside somecommand file? If thats the case then you could use grep -v "pattern"

Comment: No, you misunderstand, the pipe and grep are not working at all when called within this script that is output to a file. My grep line works fine in a regular console window, it trims the output of ./somecommand and outputs to stdout quite nicely, when that line is inserted within the script, it ignores the "| egrep "pattern1|pattern2"

Comment: did you enclose that particular line with ` (symbol to the left of 1)? Either you must include #!/bin/bash header or run it with bash scipt.sh or enclose the command within (`) symbols and run the script

Comment: I'll try that
#!/bin/bash header is included

Answer (score 0):

You may try to run your script in debug mode, like that :

```
bash -x ./script
```